# Kaminari ajax, it does NOT works, rails 3.1 and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, arrays, kaminari

I'm following https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_example/commits/ajax. I'm using kaminari 0.12.4. (I had check with 0.13.0 and and does not work). Without ajax does works fine.

I have in **users_helper.rb**

```
module UsersHelper
  def link_to_next_page(scope, name, options = {}, &block)
    param_name = options.delete(:param_name) || Kaminari.config.param_name
    link_to_unless scope.last_page?, name, {param_name => (scope.current_page + 1)}, options.merge(:rel => 'next') do
  block.call if block
  end
 end
end
```

I have in my **users_controller** the next method:

```
def followers
 @user = User.find(params[:user])
 @followers = @user.followers_by_type("user")
 @followers = Kaminari.paginate_array(@followers).page(params[:page]).per(1)
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html { render :layout => 'panel'}# followers.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @followers }
end
```

I have in my **follower.index.html.erb** the next:

```
<%= render 'followers' %>
<div id="paginator">
<%= link_to_next_page @followers, 'Next Page', :remote => true, :url => { :controller => "users", :action => "followers"} do %>
<span>No More Pages</span>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I have in partial **_followers.html.erb**

```
 <% for followers in @followers%> 
  <div class="followers">
  <%= followers.username %> 
 </div>
  <% end %>
```

I have in **followers.js.erb**

```
//$('#box').html('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'followers') %>');
//$('#box #paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@followers, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
alert ('I am follower.js.erb file');
```

**I have to see a one alert but not seen. Where is the alert? :O. The file index.js.erb does not gets nothing. Where is the problem?**

In my log appear working fine the js.erb:

```
Started GET "/maserranocaceres/followers?page=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-31 05:26:44 -0800
  Processing by UsersController#followers as JS
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "user_id"=>"maserranocaceres"}
  Rendered users/_followers.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered users/followers.html.erb (28.7ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 38ms (Views: 34.5ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: put a debugger to the action, and see what the request type is, i think it will not be what you expect...

Comment: I get with debug a object type array, but if the problem were the object, Kaminari nor should work without ajax. Kaminari works fine without ajax. I see in the log that. I watch the first result returned by the array in the log.

Comment: Rendered users/followers.html.erb (28.7ms)
its rendering in html not js, whats in the rest of your controller

Comment: The controller code its full in question. The paginator works fine without js. I get the correct object for the next page in log controller. I don't know why this does not works :(. I have others controllers with js and works fine. The problem its that the followers.js.erb don't receives nothing, that is not running.

Comment: I believe this is caused by kaminari taking advantage of the `current_page` function which is thrown off by the ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might sound a silly suggestion, but i have had issues like this in the past where changing the order of the formats helps, try:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :layout => 'panel'}# followers.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @followers }
  format.js
end
```

Comment: Thank you nodrog. I had not fix the problem. I had change the button to infinite scroll with http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ and yes works with infinite scroll, ¬¬ my face :O. I don't understand. I accept your response for your help :D. Thank you again

Comment: thanks hyperrjas, very generous of you. do bear my suggestion in mind though, i swear it happens...